# GWTP how to pass PlaceManager object to view?

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I have view, that communicates with server to upload and download file.

I've added EventHandler for Unauthorized response from server to my view.

Now I would like to redirect user to login page:

```
PlaceManager pm;
PlaceRequest placeRequest = new PlaceRequest.Builder(pm.getCurrentPlaceRequest()).nameToken(Routing.Url.login).build();
pm.revealPlace(placeRequest);
MaterialToast.fireToast("You session has expired.");
```

but for this I need `PlaceManager` object. How can I inject it to my view?

I use GWT 2.7 and GWTP

Comment: Your presenter should communicate with your server and your view with the presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't have any of this logic in the view. Instead you should create

```
public interface YourViewUiHandlers extends UiHandlers{ 
    void navigate();
}
```

Then change MyView interface to implement `HasUiHandlers<YourViewUiHandlers>` and in the ViewImpl replace `extends ViewImpl` with e`xtends ViewWithUiHandlers<YourViewUiHandlers >`

Now in your view you'll be able to call your presenter like this:

```
getUiHandlers().navigate();
```

Of course your presenter should

1. Implement YourViewUiHandlers
2. In it's contructor do something like `view.setUiHandlers(this);`

PlaceManager can be just injected into Presenter with `@Inject` annotation.
Actually if you want to make it bad and dirty `@Inject` will do it for the view as well. And if it's not View but just some composite - Initialize it with GIN using @UiField(provided=true), and then simply inject it in the constructor/set the field before `initWidget();`